# Rails Model Next/Prev Navigation Scope with datetime field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model lets say `Post` which has a column called `published_at` (datetime). My model has two instance methods called `next` and `prev`.

I'm using mysql as a database adapter.

```
def next
  self.class.unscope(:order).online
      .where('published_at > ?', published_at)
      .order('published_at ASC').first
end

def prev
  self.class.unscope(:order).online
      .where('published_at < ?', published_at)
      .order('published_at DESC').first
end
```

With the code above the navigation works if every post has another date. If some posts are on the same date just one record of those gets shown.

**Goal:** Get the next or previous record ordered by `published_at` datetime column.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you await from `next` and `prev` ?

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk the next or previous record ordered by published_at datetime column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither *"next"* , nor *"previous"* make sense in SQL. You have to *explicitly* define sort order by *uniq* key.
If you have non-uniq column as sort base, you have to add uniq one, `id` for example.

Then you have to change WHERE clause to accept rows wich have same value for your non-uniq column:

```
def next
  condition = <<~SQL
    (published_at = :published_at AND id > :id) OR
    (published_at > :published_at)
  SQL
  self.class.unscope(:order).
    online.
    where(condition, published_at: published_at, id: id).
    order(published_at: :asc, id: :asc).
    take
end
```

`prev` is constructed similarly.